# How to disable&enable button until email is valid or not

Tags: jquery, html

I have disabled the button and would like to enable it when the email will be in the correct form.
HTML:

```
<form action="" class="form-inline">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="sr-only">Email</label>
                    <input type="email" id="emailaddress" class="form-control form-control-md" placeholder="john@example.com">
                </div>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary btn-md" id="btn-subscribe">Connect</button>  
            </form>
```

JQuery:

```
var emailAddress;
  var testEmail = /^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@([A-Z0-9-]+\.)+[A-Z]{2,4}$/i;
  $('#btn-subscribe').prop('disabled', true);


$("#emailaddress").on("keyup change", function() {
   emailAddress = $(this).val();
   if( testEmail.test(emailaddress) ) { 
      $('#btn-subscribe').prop('disabled', false);
   }
});
```

Comment: Could you provide an attempt to solve this issue? thats why it's getting downvoted..

Comment: my jquery code is not an attempt? if I knew another better attempt why would I write here?

Comment: @lplatz how is that not an attempt? He basically has the whole solution and only had a typo...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works fine, however you have mistyped emailaddress in the test function call.

Change this in the javascript:
emailaddress to emailAddress

```
if( testEmail.test(emailaddress) ) {
```

to

```
if( testEmail.test(emailAddress) ) {
```

```js
var emailAddress;
  var testEmail = /^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@([A-Z0-9-]+\.)+[A-Z]{2,4}$/i;
  $('#btn-subscribe').prop('disabled', true);


$("#emailaddress").on("keyup change", function() {
   emailAddress = $(this).val();
   if( testEmail.test(emailAddress) ) { 
      $('#btn-subscribe').prop('disabled', false);
   }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="" class="form-inline">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="sr-only">Email</label>
                    <input type="email" id="emailaddress" class="form-control form-control-md" placeholder="john@example.com">
                </div>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary btn-md" id="btn-subscribe">Connect</button>  
            </form>
```